# Image Hyperlink Problem with Bootstrap Grid

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to put a grid of images on a personal website with bootstrap (at the moment just one image). The grid goes up just fine, but when the image is clicked, the page tries to create a preview or something and shows this warning:
[Follow the link, can't post images yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTDK7.png)

The text itself here "The image #1" is a clickable hyperlink to the desired page. Here is the html.

```html
<div id="portfolio">
  <div class="container-fluid p-0">
    <div class="row justify-content-center no-gutters">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
        <a href="#"><img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/portfolio/thumbnails/image.png" alt="" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you reproduce it in CodePen ? Your code is totally fine

Comment: I went ahead and pushed it up to my host as is. Slightly different, but similar problem - you can look at the html in the console: www.trenty.net  
Don't judge, site is in its infancy!

Comment: Could you share what you want when click to the image ? Open `href` link in a new tab or preview it ? Because I saw that you put `href` link to a image

Comment: Sorry, deployed the wrong repo by mistake. It's up now. I want the image to be a link to a new URL. If shows when you mouse over the image. I think the issue is in the CSS file. Its generated by someone else's workspace though - I don't know anything about CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code from `www.trenty.net`, the issue came from the below codes of `magnific-popup` library

```
$('#portfolio').magnificPopup({
        delegate: 'a:not(.portfolio-box)', // <= FIX HERE - adapt selector to not select your element
        type: 'image',
        tLoading: 'Loading image #%curr%...',
        mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
        gallery: {
            enabled: true,
            navigateByImgClick: true,
            preload: [0, 1]
        },
        image: {
            tError: '<a href="%url%">The image #%curr%</a> could not be loaded.'
        }
});
```

It will turn all `a` tag of element `#portfolio` to preview popup when you click to it.

This can solve by remove this JavaScript or adapt it (like above) to exclude your element that you doesn't want it to  open a preview popup

Comment: That was it, you nailed it. It was a call to this library in the query.js script used in the build process (again, I cloned this project, I don't know squat about query or CSS). Anyway, if someone stumbles across this (it's a popular bootstrap template repo), the `script.js` file used in the build calls this library. At first blush, removing that section entirely seems to have no meaningful impact on the website. Thanks @dungmidside you rock! My only question is how did you track down this error?

Comment: The preview popup behavior is normally archived by using JavaScript (is that can done with pure CSS ? I never try it before), so I check the source first and found the JS file, but nothing strange found, then I click to image to check and found that some class was added to page with prefix `mfp` (such as `mfp-zoom-out-cur`), I googled this word and it lead me to the `magnific-popup` library, I looked in to JS file again and found this is the root cause. That's it. Hope this will help you solve another issues